# Opening file in a different dir. in C causes Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, arrays, unix, segmentation-fault, text-files

I am trying to read from a text file "P1-Data" that is in a different directory than the current one on the Unix platform and create an array of the GPA's to calculate the average GPA using the C langauge.

Here is the text file called "P1-Data":

```
    Mark Bhatia 852600012  3.23
    Larry Burch 123236399  2.94
    Howard Huge 234123456 3.00
  # Andrew Jackson 123321123 4.00
    Lee David 666656666 3.02
    Norden Bruce 432156978 3.75
    Price Jones 121256435 2.75
    Rountree Travis 123123132 2.89
    Volek Volek 101100100 3.05
  # Fine Students 000000121 4.0
    John Bhatia 952600012  3.93
    Jangla House 123457890 2.03 
  # Tee David 666656667 3.42
  # Moriarty Hodges 898888999 2.04
    Wonder Druce 332156978 3.78
    Price Hones 121256435 2.75
    Flattree Travis 123123134 3.95
    Drew Pete 101100101 3.05
```

This is located at directory: home/.../class1/.../.../P1-DATA

Here is the C code called "stage1.c" that is giving me the errors (written in Notepad++):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int i = 0;
    float sum = 0.00, n = 0.00, avg = 0.00;

    FILE *fin;

    fin = fopen("P1-DATA", "r");

    // Keep reading in integers (which are placed into "n") until end of file (EOF)
    while(fscanf(fin, "%lf", &n) != EOF){
    // Add number to sum
    sum += n;

    // Increment counter for number of numbers read
    i++;

    // Average is sum of numbers divided by numbers read
    avg = (sum / i);
    }

    // After the loop is done, show the average
    printf("The average is %lf.\n", avg);

    fclose(fin);

    return 0;
    }
```

This is located at directory: home/.../class2/s/name/.../stage.c
(**MAIN POINT DIFFERENT DIRECTORIES**)

Also I noticed that it doesn't matter what I put into the filename I am trying to open.. I still get the segmentation fault. So I think i'm missing something before that. Maybe I need to switch to the directory the "P1-DATA" file is in?? If so.. I am not sure how to do that in C.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Also, I am on a bit of a tight schedule.. and this is just the first part of what I need to do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try putting the absolute path to P1-DATA ?

Comment: No, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Can you check that `fin != NULL` after the `fopen()`? Also, that directory you've listed doesn't look right since you have three dots instead of two in the path.

Comment: Type it in as the file name. Additionally, it is also good practice to check the file pointer, e.g., `if(fin == NULL)` print error message and exit etc. This can be done using the `errno.h` and `string.h` headers in a better way.

Comment: Thanks Mosby i'll give that a try. Thanks to you to chrisaycock.

Comment: A corefile backtrace would be nice too - this will show you where

Comment: Opening files does not cause segmentation faults.  Bad memory access causes segmentation faults.  As others have noted, you should check `fin` for `NULL` (i.e. failure to open the file) before you do stuff with it.

Comment: Are you really using "..." instead of ".."? That seems wrong.

Comment: Well it does create a core file. opening that and stage1 in vi editor looks like gibberish as well. I compiled it this way: gcc -o stage1 stage1.c in using Bash Beorne in unix

Comment: @ user1118321: no i was just using those as place holders to the actual dirs.

Comment: Checking if the file is null didn't do anything. It still crashed. How do you do a corefile backtrace Adrian?

Answer (score 4):

You have a serious problem with this line:

```
while(fscanf(fin, "%lf", &n) != EOF){
```

because `n` is a `float` rather than a `double`. Because you're trying to write a 64-bit `double` into a 32-bit `float`, all bets are off (undefined behaviour).

The standard states that the `l` prefix "specifies that ... a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `double`".

For a `float`, you should just use `%f`. Or you could just make all your floating point types into `double` - I rarely use the `float` type anymore.

---

In addition, it's considered good practice to *check* return values from functions that use them to indicate errors (along with `errno`). If the `fopen` fails, then `fin` will be set to `NULL` and it would be a bad idea to then try and use that for reading data. Something like:

```
#include <errno.h>
:
fin = fopen("P1-DATA", "r");
if (fin == NULL) {
    printf ("Error %d opening input file\n", errno);
    exit (1);
}
```

would do. There are friendlier ways to do it but that will at least let you know if an error occurred and what the error was.

---

Based on your comment that this gives you an error code of 2 (ENOENT), it's because the file doesn't exist. You need to either be *in* the directory where your data file is when you run the program, or provide the full path name to it in the `fopen`.

Comment: After adding that code from paxdiablo it outputed "Error 2 opening input file". I'm not sure what the 2 is referring to exactly.

Comment: Oh ok it means No such file or directory... hmm.. I think this means I need to set the absolute path to P1-DATA just as Borgleader suggested (initially what I was thinking as well).  I have looked on google for over 5 hours with no clear answer. :/

Comment: Please use `strerror` (POSIX) or `perror` (C standard) rather than printing raw `errno`. Also, since `fscanf(NULL, ...)` invokes undefined behavior, I would say that it's more than just "considered good practice" to check for `fopen` failure.

Comment: Oh man. It looks like I don't have those header files built into my lib Mr. Balter.

Comment: @user1690148 strerror is defined in string.h (if you're on a POSIX systems such as linux); perror is defined in stdio.h

Comment: BTW, my comment was directed at paxdiablo.

Comment: perror is for those that haven't yet memorised the contents of errno.h :-) For example, 2 is ENOENT, the file or directory isn't there. Just kidding, that's why I mentioned the friendlier ways.

Comment: I tried opening the file with the full path name. i.e. fin = fopen("~/home/.../class1/.../.../P1-DATA", "r"); I still get the same Error 2.  Note* - Of course I didn't use the "..." for the dirs., I used the actual names

Comment: @user1690148, you can't use `~` here, that's a shell thing, you need to use the real path or use `getenv` to get `$HOME` and construct the path from that.

Comment: I was going to try and set my $HOME path using getenv in .bashrc, but I  don't have the permission to because .bashrc is read only. Also there are multiple .bashrc(s) in different directories. This seems sort of strange to me. How can I use get getenv with $HOME in the C environment?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the name of the data file in your code, you
could instead specify it as a command-line parameter.

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>

if (argv[1] == NULL)
    err(1, "usage: %s datafile", argv[0]);

if ((fin = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    err(1, "Could not open \"%s\"", argv[1]);
```

(Note the check of the return value from `fopen()` above.)

You could then invoke your program with the path to the data file as a
command-line parameter:

```
% ./a.out /path/to/the/data/file
```

Note also that your data file appears to have more structure than a
simple list of floating point numbers.  Attempting to parse that data
with a simple `"%f"` format string is unlikely to work.